# Loading CSS into an HTML document

Tags: html, css

I've run into a snag. Whenever I try to load the document, the CSS layout never appears. Here's the text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <body>
      <title>Waden B. Greaux Jr.</title>
      <link href="Style/Waden_Greaux Website.css" type="text/css"
         rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <div id="header">
         <p>Hi! Welcome to the official site of Waden Greaux!</p>
         <hr />
         <p>
         <ul>
         <li><a href="Biography.html">Biography</a></li>
         <li><a href="Tips_and_Wisdom.html">Tips and Wisdom</a></li>
         <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
         <ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end of header -->
   </body>
   </p>
   <h1>Overview</h1>
   <p>Waden Greaux, age 16, is a high school student dedicated to changing the world for the better. He is a graphic designer, professional writer and journalist, programmer in 4 languages, and a full-time scholar in philosophy, mathematics, logic, and the sciences, in addition to being a computer enthusiast and investor in precious metals and stocks.</p>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS sheet:

```
body {
    background-color: #fbbdf6;
}
title {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify line-height: 1.6em;
}
p {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif font-size: 24px text-align: justify line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the role of 'head' and 'body' a bit mixed up. Head contains meta data, while all content goes into the body!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Waden B. Greaux Jr.</title>
    <link href="Style/Waden_Greaux Website.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <p>Hi! Welcome to the official site of Waden Greaux!</p>
      <hr />
      <p>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="Biography.html">Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tips_and_Wisdom.html">Tips and Wisdom</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
      <ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end of header -->
    </p>
    <h1>Overview</h1>
    <p>Waden Greaux, age 16, is a high school student dedicated to changing the world for the better. He is a graphic designer, professional writer and journalist, programmer in 4 languages, and a full-time scholar in philosophy, mathematics, logic, and the sciences, in addition to being a computer enthusiast and investor in precious metals and stocks.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) & [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp).

Thanks for responding; I still can't load the CSS file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <body>
        <title>Waden B. Greaux Jr.</title>
        <link href="Style/Waden_Greaux Website.css" type="text/css"
           rel="stylesheet" />
           </head>
                    <div id="header">
                <p>Hi! Welcome to the official site of Waden Greaux!</p><hr />
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Biography.html">Biography</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tips_and_Wisdom.html">Tips and Wisdom</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
            <ul>
        </div><!-- end of header -->
        </body>
        </p>
        <h1>Overview</h1>
        <p>Waden Greaux, age 16, is a high school student dedicated to changing the world for the better. He is a graphic designer, professional writer and journalist, programmer in 4 languages, and a full-time scholar in philosophy, mathematics, logic, and the sciences, in addition to being a computer enthusiast and investor in precious metals and stocks.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, 100pic. When I changed everything up, I still can't load the CSS file. Here's what it looks like now:

Comment: It could be the space in your css filename "Style/Waden_Greaux Website.css" - maybe try changing it to something simple like "custom.css" and then change your html to reference the css doc.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for helping me. Leo Zhao, thank you for helping me to format my code. I'll try to change the file name.

Comment: Also maybe change the file-name of your `Style` folder to lowercase `style` as well. Just makes everything easier to reference.

Comment: I've went through and changed the file name, yet the CSS document is not being loaded. I'm using Chrome to load the page; is there another way I can get the document to load using an external CSS sheet?

Comment: what does your working directory look like at the top of the folder? sounds like your href is just not working

Comment: I made sure to add all of my documents to one folder, and implement the correct directories. However,  CSS is still not loading.